# uploading HTML code to ebay store

Tags: javascript, html, css, ebay-design-templates

I have HTML design for my ebay store and now I need to upload the code to my ebay store.

Check this picture from (index.html), is this a valid code?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTCIe.png

Or I must export all the code from the files and folders to 1 page only (index.html)?

I need to understand how it works because I'm not familiar with ebay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eBay won't allow you to call external scripts (.js) or embed any `<script>` tags, when you submit the page inside eBay, it will tell you it's invalid.

CSS files and images from experience work okay from an external resource but you will need to host them and get the absolute links to the files, not relative.

Edit:

This is the ebay HTML and Script policy:
http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-javascript.html

You could get around this with a bit of script that uses document.write to write the tags in after page load. But I assume it would be in breach of the policy

*Not Allowed: Calls remote scripts and pages automatically, such as JavaScript "includes" or "iframes."*.

Comment: how can I add to my ebay store /*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */ file ??

Comment: I have added the link to the script policy to my answer. Short answer is, it isn't allowed.